# Effect of black coating on the inside of a hobby telescope's hull?

Tags: optics, visible-light

I was watching this (rather old) episode of [The Making](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QKtyIlgc6FI), where they show how a telescope is built in a factory. At [7:34](https://youtu.be/QKtyIlgc6FI?t=454), the cylindrical body of the telescope is shown to have a dark coating on the inside and the video explains that this prevents internal reflection of the light received from whatever you're observing.

I saw an interesting comment from Izumikawa Fukumi who asked if the telescope would become more accurate if they coated the inside with the [blackest black in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vantablack). How would such a dark coating affect the telescope's performance?

Comment: Many years ago Krylon ultra flat black paint was the standard of blackness. Standards have changed, but it would still be a good choice.

Comment: But how exactly does a darker coating improve the performance? Can you look further? Can you see more detail?

Comment: As R.W. Bird says, it reduces contrast. Light scattered off the inside of the telescope hits the detector, adding to the light from faint objects you want to see. Instead of a perfectly black background sky, you see a dark gray background. If the background is a bright as the fainter objects, you can't tell they are there. It limits how faint an object you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflections from the wall striking the eyepiece would reduce the contrast in the image you are trying to observe.  It wold be like the effect of city lights reflected from the atmosphere when you are trying to observe the stars.

Comment: Could you show me an image of a telescope of different contrasts? I can't quite picture it.

Comment: I can only suggest a night ride from a city to a distant wild area.

Comment: When you look at the city sky, you don't really notice that is is a little brighter than absolute black. You see the brighter stars. If the sky is really dark, you do notice how dark it is. You can see a lot more stars. Perhaps you can even see the faint milky way. Even in the city, you see the difference between a moonless night and a full moon night.